# Has == and != become bad practise?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, operators, warnings, equality

Since a few months, my IDE (WebStorm) highlights JavaScript regular equality operators with the following warning:

```
Comparioson a == b may cause unexpected type coercion.
This inspection reports usages of JavaScript quality operators which may cause unexpected
type coercions. It is considered a good practice to use the type-safe equality operators
=== and !== instead of their regular counterparts == and !=.
```

I am aware of the different behavours of both operators and I tend to use them because of their different behavour, eg. for lazy type conversions:

```
if(parseInt(val) == val) // val can be safely converted to int
```

However, the IDE is adding warnings to **all** occurences of `==`, so the above does not *feel right anymore*. I'm could convert all these parts into something much less readable:

```
if(parseInt(val).toString() === val) // be happy webstorm
```

Is this really the way to go; or should I rather ignore/disable these warnings?

Comment: `==` is only good for `if(x==null)` since it hits `undefined` too

Comment: i.e. not "good" really

Comment: If, for example, `val` has leading or trailing spaces or zeroes, your "*solution*" will not work.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: how is that not good? I've never wanted to split hairs between null/undefined; both mean "nope". Why type more than needed to be legible; let the compiler do to the work.

Comment: Because explicit is better than implicit, @dandavis.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: usually, but the two empty values of JS is a bug. When do you need to distinguish?

Comment: @dandavis [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5076944)

Comment: @4castle: that doesn't answer my question. I just don't believe anyone's ever had a real need to use `if(x===undefined||x===null)` instead of `if(x==null)`, since it always does the exact same thing...

Comment: It's not helpful to mark this question as a duplicate of a question that was closed for being not constructive. It's essentially saying *this* question is not constructive.

Comment: @dandavis All bad practices are sometimes useful. That doesn't mean you should use them. Considering how most people consider `==` to be bad practice, `if (x == null)` could be interpreted as a typo for `if (x === null)`.

Comment: @RobG: It was a bit of a crapshoot I admit but an easy way to point to the best existing "for more information..." source. To be quite frank my patience with SO is so low nowadays that I don't really care :)

Comment: @RobG: Not really - "duplicate" doesn't actually mean "duplicate" and hasn't for some time; it means "this has been asked before to the extent that your answer is over _there_". Furthermore, I don't consider that other question to be "not constructive"; fortunately you guys have already reopened it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that any form of type coercion, if unexpected for types that may not be known at runtime (like any dynamic language) is bad practice.

For example, these are both truthy:

```
 "0" == false
 "0"
```

While this is falsey:

```
 false
```

Comment: If you're trying to compare two values and you have absolutely no idea of either type, how will you know whether `===` will achieve a predicable result any more than `==`? If you're that much in the dark, you'll need to do some type checking before equality evaluation anyway.

Comment: @robg Because explicit is always better than implicit. If you have no idea what may he passed, like maybe in a serialized, you could check for a few cases explicitly and throw an error or have a default handler for the remaining cases. It also saves you cases where you originally design a function for one use and then extend it to a new use and get unexpected results because of implicit behavior.

Comment: Those comments apply to both cases. My issue is with the generalisation of `===` as "best practice" without any consideration of what "best practice" actually is. It will often lead to different results in different cases and type coercion is done all the time, to get ISO weekday I use `date.getDay() || 7`. So it might be appropriate to use `===` in some cases and `==` in others Repurposing code can lead to many issues, not just those arising from abstract vs strict comparison. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this has been best practice for almost two decades.

The warning is quite clear (even explaining *why* it's in place), and you'll find the same advice in your JavaScript books as well as widely across the web.

So, I can't comprehend why you'd consider ignoring or even disabling it.

---

You can find more information on when to pick `==` and when to pick `===` here:

- [When is it OK to use == in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768729/when-is-it-ok-to-use-in-javascript)

Comment: You're implying that implicit type coercion is a bad thing. If your application is ambiguous enough that you are not sure what types/values you are going to be comparing, I think your code has bigger issues. `==` is equivalent to `===` when the values are of the same type.

Comment: @mhodges But what about people misusing your library or new developers coming on the project passing wrong values and getting odd results? Using `===` helps everyone in the long run and is well worth the extra key press.

Comment: The term "best practice" is pretty meaningless if it's not backed up with criteria for determining "best".

Comment: @4castle: Perhaps (though see my comment under the question). I've now converted the dupevote into a cross-reference

Comment: @mhodges: No, as the warning text states, the problem is _unexpected_ type coercions. If you know you want a coercion then fine go ahead.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Exactly. If you want type coercions (which, in many cases are helpful) then `==` is beneficial over `===`. Meaning that `===` is not a "best practice", but rather the correct choice in many situations. However, `==` is also the correct choice in many situations. Point in case - know the language and use the syntax appropriately.

Comment: @mhodges: "best default practice", perhaps

Comment: @BoundaryImposition In all reality, there are only a small handful of values that produce unexpected results when using implicit type coercion in comparison expressions. If you can know those and avoid them, `==` is completely safe. It's kind of like the `var` vs `let/const` debate. let/const is not the new var, `() =>` is not the new `function` and `===` is not the "new" `==`. They each serve different, yet very legitimate purposes.

Comment: @mhodges: Indeed.